# hostgator cron job not working

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I am having a problem in making my cron job to work,

here is the only code in my php file:

sendreport.php

```
mail("someone@somewhere.com", "test email", "test message");
```

and here is the cron job in the cpanel:

```
0 10 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6 php /home/username/public_html/foldername/sendreport.php
```

I am using hostgator.

The cron job should run every 10 am from Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and Saturday but seems like it is not working.

I was wondering if I am doing it correct?

Comment: You could try appending  `2>>/path/to/error.log` to your command to write the potential errors to a log file.

Comment: @Matt I am new to this. Where can I find the error log? Thanks..

Comment: can anyone help me with this problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add `2>> /home/username/public_html/foldername/error.log` after the command in your cron line it will write any errors into the file error.log in this directory. The file is created by this command.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I've appended the suggested code but am not getting any error log file being created.

Comment: Same issue. Started suddenly with no change to the CRON job script. No error output to the log. I can run the php script manually no problem and without error. Knowing HostGator, they've just switch something off or made an undocumented change ...

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with your code. Hostgator blocks cronjobs running more frequent then every 15minutes. (YES I KNOW THIS IS ALMOST A YEAR OLD - ITS FOR FUTURE PEOPLE)

> Cron Job Limits
>
> Shared and Reseller
>
> You may NOT run a cron job more often than every 15 minutes.

Ref: https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/what-are-cron-jobs

Comment: OP says they are running once per day.

Comment: That's true. I have the same issue with hostgator. Fortunately I have another webhosting account in another company, without limit. So I run the cron jobs from there calling some curl page to hostgator script.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Justin said. Per this [article](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-are-cron-jobs) shared and reseller can only fire at most every 15 minutes.

Comment: OP says they are running once per day.